# Using ffmpeg to convert flv to mp4 on debian 6

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, flv, mp4

I am using ffmpeg on debian version squeeze/sid to convert flv to mp4.I need to view final output on iphone, ipad. I have tried many different combinations but have not succeeded in converting the file properly.

Information about the sample flv file is as follows - via command ffmpeg -i sample.flv

```
  FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:27:59, gcc: 4.4.3
Input #0, flv, from 'sample.flv':
  Duration: 00:01:06.90, start: 2.079000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 352x200, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 44100 Hz, mono, s16
At least one output file must be specified
```

when i try using command - ffmpeg -i sample.flv -sameq -ar 22050 sample.mp4

I get error with following output.

```
ffmpeg -i sample.flv -sameq -ar 22050 sample.mp4
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:27:59, gcc: 4.4.3
Input #0, flv, from 'sample.flv':
  Duration: 00:01:06.90, start: 2.079000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 352x200, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 44100 Hz, mono, s16
Output #0, mp4, to 'sample.mp4':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 352x200, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x0000, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Unsupported codec for output stream #0.1
```

I am not very conversant with ffmpeg and any help, pointers would highly appreciated.

Many thanks is advance.

Comment: If you just need to convert things, take a look at VLC. And it's just a `sudo apt-get install vlc` away. Also, I think the problem is that you don't have FLV support installed.

Comment: Thanks Linuxios,

I have compiled libmp3lame. Now i get another error- 

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mpeg4 @ 0x19ee400]Error, Invalid timestamp=11637, last=13630
Video encoding failed

Comment: Instead of compiling it manually, which can be very error prone, how about just `sudo apt-get install vlc`?

Comment: try [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php/)

Comment: That's an *old* version of FFmpeg you've got there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

> Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x0000, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s

ffmpeg usually tries to pick an appropriate encoder for the output container format you specify. In this case it has chosen the "audio encoder" 0x0000 for some reason (probably a bug/old version/no codecs available)

In this case, however, you can tell it which encoder to use. To pick one, have a look at the output of `ffmpeg -codecs`. You can choose an audio codec to encode with by putting `-acodec codec` before the output file name you specify.

Since you're encoding for apple devices, try choosing an encoder that produces AAC audio, as that tends to be apple's favorite audio codec.